# Getting a Timer to do things at irregular intervals in java

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to write a program that will fire of several events at specified yet irregular intervals. I looked at the java.util Timer class and the javax.swing Timer class, but neither of them have just what I need. I will be scheduling a lot of events, and it will take a noticeable amount of time to schedule. Therefore, t the best of my knowledge, the java.util timer won't work because it starts the timer as soon as the event is scheduled the timer starts. I need the Timer to start at the same time for all of the events, which the javax.swing timer allows you to do, but it only allows regularly spaced events. Can anyone recommend something I can do?

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear to me.  Can you explain what you want?

Comment: yeah you're not specific enough in your requirements to give you a solution. For ex., can you schedule your tasks using cron in linux/unix etc?

Comment: Basically, I have a whole lot of things I want to do once, all spaced at irregular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Quartz: http://quartz-scheduler.org/ it's very flexible.